# How to setup static LoadBalancer IP for a service in OCI kubernetes cluster?

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, service, static, static-ip-address

I have a 3-node OKE cluster setup in Oracle cloud.

I deployed an nginx ingress controller in the cluster.
I'm mapping the FQDN test.myapp.com to the EXTERNAL_IP of that nginx ingress controller service.

Whenever I re-install the ingress controller during the time of testing, it gets different EXTERNAL_IP and I have to map the FQDN again to that new IP.

So it will be better if I can specify a static loadBalancer IP during the time of nginx ingress controller installation. Like this:

```
nginx-ingress:
  controller:
    service:
      loadBalancerIP: "125.23.119.23"
```

How can I achieve this in Oracle cloud (with OKE)?

Comment: Would ExternalDNS help you?
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns#externaldns
ExternalDNS allows you to control DNS records dynamically via Kubernetes resources. And from its documentation I see it supports Oracle Cloud Infrastructure DNS.

This will help you to not rely on static External_IP and also automate creation/removal of DNS records by monitoring your `Service Annotations` and/or `Ingress Host`

Comment: @rock'nrolla But it seems that it doesn't support my service provider. What I would need is something like this for oracle : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#create-a-static-ip-address ( This is in azure cloud ).

Comment: I might not be thinking straight but what happens if you use a pre-reserved IP (like ElasticIP in AWS) in the `loadBalancerIP` of the nginx controller service - just like you mentioned. I see nginx ingress helm chart allows this : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml#L271
Does the LB which gets created not uses this IP?

Comment: @rock'nrolla I tried to set a `loadBalancerIP` for a sample service. But the externalIP remained `<pending>`. And there was error `Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: invalid service: OCI does not support setting LoadBalancerIP`. That means it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle cloud Infrastructure(OCI) supports creating `LoadBalancer` services in kubernetes clusters, and allows setting the `LoadBalancerIP` parameter too.

But first, you have to create a **Reserved Public IP address** in OCI, and then specify that IP address as `LoadBalancerIP` of your service.

You can do it as :

- Go to OCI console :
  `Networking -> IP management -> Reserved Public IPs`.
   Click on `Reserve Public IP Address`
  Provide a name, and select source `Oracle` if that is the only public IP pool you have (default).
  Click on the Reserve button to get a reserved public IP address.
- In OCI console, look at : 
  `Networking -> IP management -> Reserved Public IPs` 
  ( You can see a **Reserved Public IP** there, but not attached to any VNIC) 
  `Networking -> Load Balancers` 
  ( No Loadbalancers are listed with the IP address that we reserved )
- Create a `LoadBalancer` type service in kubernetes cluster using `kubectl` with `LoadbalancerIP` provided with value of our Reserved IP Address.
- Check `kubectl get svc`, and you can see that the Reserved Public IP address is assigned to the service.
- In  OCI console, look at : 
  `Networking -> IP management -> Reserved Public IPs` 
  ( You can see a public IP address reserved, attached to a VNIC for an LB) 
  `Networking -> Load Balancers` 
  ( A layer-4 Loadbalancer is added automatically with the IP address that we reserved )

That means, when you create a `Reserved Public IP`, you are just reserving it for future use. A layer-4 load balancer is created and associated with that IP address only when a `LoadBalancer` type service is created with this Reserved IP address.

If you delete that LoadBalancer type service, the layer-4 loadbalancer also gets deleted. But the Reserved public IP still remains there. You can assign that IP address to another service next time.

These documentations have explanations regarding this topic :

- https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengcreatingloadbalancer.htm#contengcreatingloadbalancer_topic_Specifying_Load_Balancer_Reserved_IP
- https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingpublicIPs.htm#console-reserved

Answer (score -2):

Please ensure you install nginx ingress controller using helm chart https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm

Please make sure that your Ingress Controller runs as a DaemonSet only on the Infra Nodes of your Openshift Cluster using helm chart values.

Then create an Oracle Cloud Load Balancer to point to the NodePort of the Infra Nodes on which Ingress Controller Service is listening on.

This is the way that OpenShift Router works.

Comment: Currently, I'm refering this to install ingress controller : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/

Comment: I am using https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ which is using https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx so it is managed inside Kubernetes Organization